# How can I find exactly phrase with an array field in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api, elasticsearch-query

I have index with field `singers` mapping like:

```
"singers": {
    "type": "string",
    "index_name": "singer",
    "analyzer": "unicode_analyzer"
}
```

Example data like:

```
"singers": [
    "Đàm Vĩnh Hưng",
    "Thanh Lam (NSƯT)"
]
```

Now I want to find if index has exactly singer name "Đàm Vĩnh Hưng", how can I do that?

Currently, I tried:

```
{
   "query": {
      "terms": {
         "singers": [
            "Đàm Vĩnh Hưng"
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

But the result is empty.

Any advice will be welcome. Thank you guys.

After tries, I resolved this when I use `match_phrase`. I will keep this for anyone who meet the same problem. Please close this. Thank you.

Comment: @Val Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `match_phrase`.

```
{
   "query": {
      "match_phrase": {
         "singers": "Đàm Vĩnh Hưng"
      }
   }
}
```